# What is the Earth Engine server side version of JavaScript's toFixed() function for rounding off to certain decimal places?

Tags: google-earth-engine, decimal-points

I want to round off an `ee.Number()` object to two decimal places. Right now I am using `.toFixed()` of JavaScript, but how to do that using a server-side function? I tried `toFloat()` but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work as follows, though I am unsure if this is proper rounding within the GEE:

```
// make an ee.Number with more than 2 decimals
var number = ee.Number(76.457034897543523)

// round to two decimals using divide/multiply
var rounded = number.multiply(100).round().divide(100)

// format to string and make string a number
var rounded2 = ee.Number.parse(number.format('%.2f'))
```

Comment: Thanks, serves the purpose